# TypeError : string is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hello guys I am new to node js

i am trying to run following code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'); // Templating library adapter for Express

    app.engine('html', cons.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('hello', { name : 'World' });
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res){
        res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
    });

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
```

then error comes

> TypeError: string is not a function
>      at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)
>      at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
>      at C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\test_coso.js:10:6
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>      at next (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>      at expressInit (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at trim_prefix (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>      at C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>      at next (C:\Users\YAm\Desktop\mongodb\work\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)

Comment: have you installed all the dependencies like expressjs and consolidate?

Comment: It looks like your call to `res.render()` is being served by the Express implementation which expects `res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])`.  My guess it that either your templating/view engine is not properly installed or initialized or you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the documentation for [express res.render()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render). I think there is a problem with your syntax.

```
// send the rendered view to the client
res.render('index');

// if a callback is specified, the rendered HTML string has to be sent explicitly
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  res.send(html);
});

// pass a local variable to the view
res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function(err, html) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not having any problem and is working fine for me

Do the following things to debug the issue

1. Check your `hello.html` file inside `views` folder remove all the
   html code and try to put some simple "Hello Word"
2. Create a new Folder and copy paste the js script and the views
   folder then try npm install express, consolidate and swig
3. Check the node version for v5.5.0 it is working fine without any
   issue